# How to make sure iOS Cordova Phone Gap version 5.2 plugins are installed and working

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am just trying to use the notifications plugin to start, I will need others later but having a problem getting it to work. When I try to use

```
    navigator.notification.alert('test', myCallbackFn);
```

It says navigator.notification is undefined. my config file added this line when I added the plugin via CLI.

```
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" spec="~0.3.0" />
```

I am using this in the deviceReady function, where it looks like cordova.js is loaded without any problems.

Here is my whole snippet:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function onDeviceReady() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);

              try{
                //alert(navigator.notification);
                navigator.notification.alert("test", function(){});
              }catch(error){
                alert(error);
              };

        }, false);
    </script>
```

Also I did make sure to run this each time

```
    $ cordova build ios
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use phonegap, I use cordova. The reason is, that phonegap uses older versions of cordova and you have less plugins in phonegap. The dialog plugin, which you are using, is v0.3 the current official version from Apache is v1.1.1.

To check, that the notification plugin is running, just use in your deviceready function:

```
console.log(navigator.notification);
```

Attention: Before you can use the console, you have to install the console plugin, found here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs

Do it with:

```
 cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
```

But I suggest to restart the project and use cordova instead of phonegap, if you have an Apple machine.

Start from here and always use the edge version (select it in the top right corner):

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: Ok I am actually pretty new to phone gap/cordova and thought they were the same thing basically. So that might be part of my problem. I tried a couple other plugins and they seem to get installed and show up in my config.xml but I can't access them with my code.

Comment: I started a new project following your suggested link and got everything work, thanks for your help!